# Using Python or Other Scripting Language With IIOP

Tags: python, iiop

I have a java version of an IIOP client but I am having all sorts of issues with connectivity. I would like to build the client in python but haven't found anything that would let me.  Is there such a thing?

Comment: Is there a chance to use something else to IIOP?

Comment: I would prefer something dynamic and cross-platform.  I have used C# and Java so far.

Comment: Yes, but, do you have to connect using IIOP as the protocol or can you chose something else?

Comment: Aha sorry, I am interacting with a third party server and the only API they exposed is through IIOP unfortunately.

Comment: This is what google returns : http://infolab.stanford.edu/~akamatsu/IIOPConnectHome.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[omniORB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411943/using-python-or-other-scipting-language-with-iiop) supports Python.